# Is there a way to use font-feature-settings in React Native

Tags: react-native, fonts, styled-components

I'm using a custom font that supports different alternations. I would like to be able to toggle them. Is it really possible as of now in React Native?

```
font-feature-settings: 'ss01'on, 'liga' off;
```

Answer (score -2):

as far as i know:

for example:
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;

you may want to use the link below as a reference for the full features:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/opentype/spec/featurelist